# Create permission level & add user to list in sp-hosted app

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to follow the exact example code from

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246414(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246414%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

to get it work in an app web. I execute the code from console within app web, so there should be no cross domain issues. I get the error "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource" although i am a site owner. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As I know SharePoint apps for Office 365 including SharePoint hosted apps can't have full control permissions.  They will not be approved by Store. So, most likely you will never be able to use this functionality under permissions of app.